# How to Extract a Specific Value from Nested JSON Data using LINQ?

Tags: c#, json, linq

```
var json= "data": {
    "results": abc,
    "faresAvailable": {
      "thamil-": {
        "totals": 1,
        "isSumOfSector": false,
        "fareAvailabilityKey": "MH5UM35_UVB_VDNPN1pCSVh_MTAwN35_MTl_MX5OQk9NTUFBMDE5MDAxMH5YITA-",
        "fares": idk,
      },
      "rocky-": {
        "totals": 2,
        "isSumOfSector": false,
        "fareAvailabilityKey": "MH5UN35_UVB_VDdPN1pCSVh_MTAwN35_MTl_MX5OQk9NTUFBMDE5MDAxMH5YITE-",
        "fares": idk too,
      }
    },
    "currencyCode": "INR",
    "includeTaxesAndFees": true,
    "bundleOffers": null
  }
}
```

I have a json file like this
and I am using this query

```
var A=from a in json[data]
select new {
  fareAvailabilityKey = json["faresAvailable"].Values().Select(a=>a["fareAvailabilityKey"].ToString())
};
```

I want the output like:

```
fareAvailabilityKey    
MH5UM35_UVB_VDNPN1pCSVh_MTAwN35_MTl_MX5OQk9NTUFBMDE5MDAxMH5YITA-
MH5UN35_UVB_VDdPN1pCSVh_MTAwN35_MTl_MX5OQk9NTUFBMDE5MDAxMH5YITE-
```

some one please help..!

Comment: Please specify what library are you using and provide code which can be copy-pasted and compiled without significant modification.

Comment: That's not actually valid JSON, looks like you've mangled it a bit too much. Why not just deserialize into a proper object model

Comment: Im using this : using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

Comment: yes, I  did. cause, I want two values in the json by giving 'faresAvailable' mainly and need to skip my names, like thamil and rocky. And directly access the "fareAvailabilityKey" values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the one of the way to get desired output using `JObject`

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var fareAvailabilityKeys = jsonObject["data"]["faresAvailable"]
    .Children()
    .Select(a => (string)a["fareAvailabilityKey"]);

foreach (var fareAvailabilityKey in fareAvailabilityKeys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fareAvailabilityKey);
}
```

Comment: Its still show this error message..! System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken,System.String]

Comment: @Rocky, that is not an error message. That looks like the result of `.ToString()` (which `Console.WriteLine` implies).

Comment: can do in one line:
var items = jsonObject["data"]["faresAvailable"].Value<JToken>()
    .Select(s=> s.Children()["fareAvailabilityKey"].ToString())